# How to load a huge graph into memory to repeatedly find shortest path between two given nodes?

Tags: java, php

I am writing an application in which I need to load a huge graph into memory and answer "shortest path between x and y" for different pairs of x and y. The graph is static and can be loaded once for all into main memory.

The query for shortest path between x and y is made by a UI written in PHP. How can I keep the graph loaded in memory and find the shortest path repeatedly in an efficient way ? Is writing a JAVA daemon going to help ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to write a service/daemon which run all the time and keeps the data in memory.  By huge, how big is it?

Comment: Its a little over 1 million nodes. Yes I understand that I would have to write a daemon. But I am not sure how I can write a daemon in java and also have PHP code calling JAVA Apis ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use memcached to keep the graph loaded in memory. PHP can easily read/write data from memcached.

You would need to run memcached as a daemon / service on server.

Comment: I believe memcached stores key value pairs. How can I store a DAG where one node can be link to more than one other node and vice versa ?

Comment: One way is to:


1. Keep all nodes as name value pairs, name would ne "ID" of node and value would be node. 
2. FOr each node, one of the attributes would be list of nodes it connects to